# Double Induction Technique: Prove $\forall m,n \in \mathbb N (m>n \implies 10^{-m}<10^{-n})$

Tags: induction, solution-verification

One of the claims I am trying to prove in Tao's "*Analysis I*" is as follows:

$\forall m,n \in \mathbb N (m>n \implies 10^{-m}<10^{-n})$

After a little searching, this requires "**double induction**", a strategy that basically involves *tiered* inductions (where multiple inductions are embedded within an overarching *parent* induction). I have never carried out a proof like this before, so I just wanted some confirmation that my process is correct.

> The only additional information required for this proof is the fact that addition and positive multiplication preserves order.

---

**Base Case of Parent Induction**: Prove the following for $n=0$

$$\forall m \in \mathbb N (m>0 \implies 10^{-m} < 1)$$

*Base Case for Embedded Induction*: Prove $m=1$

1. $1>0$
2. $10^{-1} = \frac{1}{10} \lt 1$

*Assumption for Embedded Induction*: Assume for some $m=k>0$, $(k\gt 0 \implies 10^{-k} < 1$)

*Induction Step for Embedded Induction*: Prove for $m=k+1$, $(k+1 \gt 0 \implies 10^{-(k+1)}\lt 1)$.

By assumption, $k \gt 0$. Therefore $k+1 \gt 0$.

Further, by assumption, $10^{-k} \lt 1$. Multiplying both sides by $10^{-1}$:

$10^{-k}*10^{-1} = 10^{-(k+1)} \lt 1*10^{-1}=\frac{1}{10}$

$10^{-(k+1)} \lt \frac{1}{10} \implies 10^{-(k+1)} \lt 1$ (note that this actually makes use of our base case of $\frac{1}{10} < 1$ )

Therefore, $$\forall m \in \mathbb N (m>0 \implies 10^{-m} < 1)$$

---

**Assumption Case for Parent Induction:** Assume for some $n=n'$...

$$\forall m \in \mathbb N (m>n' \implies 10^{-m} < 10^{-n'})$$

---

**Induction Step for Parent Induction**: Prove the following for some $n=n'+1$...

$$\forall m \in \mathbb N (m>(n'+1) \implies 10^{-m} < 10^{-(n'+1)})$$

*Base Case for Embedded Induction:* Prove for $m=n'+2$

Remember, by assumption, $m>n' \implies 10^{-m} < 10^{-n'}$

Consider some $m'$ where $m'=n'+1$. Then it must be true that $m'>n'$ because $n'+1 > n'$.

Therefore, $10^{-m'} = 10^{-(n'+1)} < 10^{-n'}$

Multiplying both sides by $10^{-1}$ we get: $10^{-(n'+1)}*10^{-1} < 10^{-n'}*10^{-1}$

But this is simply: $10^{-(n'+2)} < 10^{-(n+1)'}$. Note that if $m=n'+2$ then $m>n'+1$ so the base case is proven.

*Assumption for Embedded Induction:* Assume for some $m=k>n'+1$, $(k>n'+1 \implies 10^{-k} < 10^{-(n'+1)})$

*Induction Step for Embedded Induction*: Prove for $m=k+1$, $(k+1 > n'+1 \implies 10^{-(k+1)} < 10^{-(n'+1)})$

By assumption, for $k>n'+1$, $(10^{-k} < 10^{-(n'+1)})$.

Multiplying both sides by $10^{-1}$, we have: $10^{-k}*10^{-1} < 10^{-(n'+1)}*10^{-1}$

Therefore: $10^{-(k+1)} < 10^{-(n'+2)}$

Recalling our base case: $10^{-(k+1)} < 10^{-(n'+2)} < 10^{-(n'+1)}$.

Thus: $10^{-(k+1)} < 10^{-(n'+1)}$.

Note that $k > n'+1$, which means $k+1 > n' +1$.

$\forall m,n \in \mathbb N (m>n \implies 10^{-m}<10^{-n}) \ \ \ \ \square$

Any suggestions (or corrections) would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You could probably get away with single induction.

Comment: @CharlieFrohman oh, interesting. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Prove that $1>10^{-n}$ for all counting numbers by induction. Then multiply both sides by ten to a power.